# Creating macro for function

Tags: assembly, x86

I was wondering why my macro would always say attempted to divide by 0 everytime I try to do my division step. I have no idea on what I'm doing wrong, the macro seems simple enough, did i mess up somewhere on my divide macros?

Here's my code so far

```
.386

.model flat

 StartDiv macro
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8
    mov eax, [ebp + NumA]
    mov ebx, [ebp + NumB]
endm

Divide macro
    cdq
    idiv ebx
endm

FinishDiv macro
    mov [ebp - 4], eax
    add esp, 8
    pop ebp
endm

StartMul macro
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8
    mov eax, [ebp + NumA]
    mov ecx, [ebp + NumB]
endm

Multiply macro
    imul ecx
endm

FinishMul macro
    mov [ebp - 4], eax
    add esp, 8
    pop ebp
    ret
endm

StartSq macro
    mov eax, [esp+4]
endm

Square macro
    imul eax
endm

FinishSq macro
    ret
endm

.code

extrn           _PrintResult:proc
NumA            = 8
NumB            = 12
Remainder       = 16

_Divide proc
    StartDiv
    Divide
    FinishDiv
_Divide endp

_Multiply proc
    StartMul
    Multiply
    FinishMul
_Multiply endp

_Square proc
    StartSq
    Square
    FinishSq
_Square endp

end
```

Here's the main code:
    #include

```
using namespace std;

enum ResultCode     {ShowSquare, ShowMultiply, ShowDivide, ShowRemainder,       ShowDivideFailure};
enum SuccessCode    {Failure, Success};

extern "C" SuccessCode Divide (long, long, long &, long &);
extern "C" long Multiply (long, long);
extern "C" void PrintResult (ResultCode, long);
extern "C" long Square (long);

void main ()
{
long Num1; 
long Num2;
long Result;
long Remainder;
do
    {
    cout << "Enter Number to Square" << endl;
    cin >> Num1;
    Result = Square (Num1);
    cout << "Square is: " << Result << endl;
    cout << "Enter two numbers to multiply" << endl;
    cin >> Num1 >> Num2;
    Result = Multiply (Num1, Num2);
    cout << "Result of multiply is: " << Result << endl;
    cout << "Enter mumber to divide into then number to divide by" << endl;
    cin >> Num1 >> Num2;
    if (Divide (Num1, Num2, Result, Remainder) == Success)
            cout << "Result is " << Result << " and remainder is " <<    Remainder << endl;
        else
            cout << "Attempted division by zero";
    } while (Result > 0);
}

void PrintResult (ResultCode PrintCode, long Value)
{
switch (PrintCode)
    {
    case ShowSquare:
            cout << "Display of square is: " << Value << endl;
            break;
    case ShowMultiply:
            cout << "Display of multiply is: " << Value << endl;
            break;
    case ShowDivide:
            cout << "Display of divide is " << Value << endl;
            break;
    case ShowRemainder:
            cout << "Display of remainder is " << Value << endl;
            break;
    case ShowDivideFailure:
            cout << "Display of Division by zero" << endl;
            break;
    default:
            cout << "Error in assembly routines" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Macros are completely useless here. Use macros whenever you need some repetitive chunk of code etc - not for things that are used just once. The way you did it just makes easy code hard to read.

Comment: BTW - shouldnt' your NumA, NumB definitions be places before they are used?

Answer (score 0):

You may solve your problems using inlined assembly - you'll be able to debug things then. You may use so called **naked** functions which tells c/c++ compiler **let me take complete responsibility for my code here** (compiler will not interfere at all - no preamble, no leave code, no return - all up to you.

Here is how your division stuff may look like:

```
__declspec(naked) int my_div(int num1, int num2, int *result, int *reminder)
{
    _asm{
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        //sub esp, 8  // for 2 local int(32bit) variables - but you do not have any

        //mov dword ptr[ebp-4], 3   // set one local var to 3
        //mov dword ptr[ebp-8], 4   // set one local var to 4

        mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+8]   // dividend
        cdq                          //   sign extend EAX's content to EDX:EAX
        mov ebx, dword ptr [ebp+12]  // divisor  
        idiv ebx                     //   divide EDX:EAX by EBX and put result in EAX and reminder in EDX
        mov ecx, dword ptr [ebp+16]  // pointer to result
        mov dword ptr [ecx], eax     //   write result back
        mov ecx, dword ptr [ebp+20]  // pointer to reminder
        mov dword ptr [ecx], edx     //   write reminder back

        // return value must be in EAX - but it is up to you now
        //add esp, 8 // remove space for local vars

        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int dividend = 63;
    int divisor = 6;
    int result = 0;
    int reminder = 0;

    my_div(dividend, divisor, &result, &reminder);
    printf("%d/%d = %d rem %d\n", dividend, divisor, result, reminder );

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
63/6 = 10 rem 3
```

Here are some hints & opinions from me:

First - do not use macros here - use for repetitive code.

2nd - here is your div code:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 8
mov eax, [ebp + NumA]
mov ebx, [ebp + NumB]

cdq
idiv ebx

mov [ebp - 4], eax
add esp, 8
pop ebp
```

There are few problems here:

- sub esp, 8 and add esp, 8 - useless - you do not need space for local variables as you do not use them
- NumA and NumB are defined below so may not work (have no way to check it so check by yourself)
- you must read about **cdecl** calling convention because you do not know how to use it ([old new thing calling conv](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/02/47184.aspx), [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions))
- return values should be in EAX register (your success, failed values) - add appropriate code yourself as I skipped it

Next bunch of problems for this code:

```
if (Divide (Num1, Num2, Result, Remainder) == Success)
```

- as I said your Success value must be returned via EAX
- result and reminder must be passed but not this way - what you need it to pass pointers to them - like in my example and from within the div routine you use these pointers to write result and reminder back

In general all above applies to the rest of the code.

Hope this helps and happy coding.